# http_response_code not working inside a try-catch block in PHP

Tags: php, try-catch

I'm having an issue when I use a try catch block and `http_response_code()` function of php..

I need to response with a 403 error when I have catched an error and print a message when everything goes ok.

The problem is that, when enter in the "catch" part, they not sending the 403 error code and send 200 status OK instead.

This is the code (taken from php page and modified with my own needs)

```
<?php
    function inverso($x) {
        if (!$x) {
            throw new Exception('Division by zero.');
        }
        return 1/$x;
    }

    try {
        echo inverso(0) . "\n";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Exception!: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
        http_response_code(403);
    }
?>
```

This code works well in PHP 5.5.9., but not in PHP 5.6.24

The version of PHP can be the problem?

Edit1: Outside the "try-catch" block the http_response_code(403) works fine.

Edit2: Outside the "try-catch" block the headers_sent() function returns empty. And inside the "try-catch" block the headers_sent() function returns "1"

Hope anyone can help me! Thanks!

Comment: Works for me in PHP5.6.25

Comment: Define _Does not work_